# Configuring nginx to serve

Tags: nginx, routing

I have a rails apps hosted in my aws server and using nginx as a proxy server. In the same instance I am running an api server on port 3004. In nignx conf file I made some change so that the contents from the api server can be accessed via domain.com/api while my rails app can be access via domain.com .

When I access domain.com/api I will get a list of endpoints that I can access.But the issue is I have to access those enpoints like this domain/apicategories. It is incorrect. I have to access them like this domain/api/categories. Below is my nignx conf file

```
    upstream postgrest {
      server localhost:3004;
      keepalive 64;
    }


    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;

      root /home/deploy/test/current/public;

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
      location /api {
         default_type  application/json;
         proxy_hide_header Content-Location;
         add_header Content-Location  /api$upstream_http_content_location;
         proxy_set_header  Connection "";
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_pass http://postgrest/;


   }
```

Comment: I guess you're missing a slash somewhere. Try adding one after "location /api" at a guess, but other places will be worth trying too. Report back results by editing your question to add more information. Your question is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you. I added a location /api/ in the conf file and it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim helped you with comments, you were missing a trailing slash `/` in your **location** block.

Excerpt from [NGINX Official Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) :

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
>   character, and requests are processed by one of **proxy_pass**,
>   **fastcgi_pass**, **uwsgi_pass**, **scgi_pass**, or **memcached_pass**, then the
>   special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI
>   equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent
>   redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with
>   the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI
>   and location could be defined like this:

So these two are not equal in this case :

```
location /api/ {
    ...
}

IS NOT EQUAL WITH

location /api {
    ...
}
```

But if you want to avoid such mistakes in cases that you need to match **yourDomain/api** or **yourDomain/api/** as full strings, you can use the following regex matching :

```
location ~ ^/api/?$ {
    ...
}
```

Tilde `~` symbol will enable regex matching, and `/?` will be permitting one or zero slash `/` symbols before the end of input.

Comment: Great that someone could answer the why, I learned something too :)

Comment: @Tim I'm glad to hear that, good luck mate.